# Having a condensation problem under a tarp that's enclosed outside with 2 heaters. Help!

Tags: weather, rain, shelter, tarp-tents

Ok so I have attached a 2 sided massive tarp to my house and then added tarps around the sides to create walls. It's built over my back porch and a concrete patio with some ground showing and some ground covered with pallets. Needed a workshop so this is my alternative. Did this at my other house and didn't have this problem as much but also had I think 2 for sure but maybe 3 tarps as the ceiling. I have a propane heater, an electric heater, a regular household standing fan and a big stand up shop fan. And a hole for ventilation but maybe it's not big enough or something.

This tarp is like raining on the inside is the best way to describe it. Right directly above the heater is ok but the rest of it is a downpour. I have the tarp sloping downward from the house but I'm at a loss on how to stop all of this condensation. Anyone with more knowledge about this?

I have tried not using the propane heater but that made things worse. Like when it's raining. Electric heaters may answer the question just hate what it will do to the power bill.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be moved to diy.stackexchange.com

Comment: The propane heater will be generating a lot of water, as will any gas or liquid fuel heater. The tarp directly above the heater is warm enough that the water does not condense there. There is a surprising statistic that one pint of paraffin produces 1¼ pints of water (as vapour). I suggest you get a solid fuel stove with a flue vented to the outside.

Comment: Any double layer (slightly spaced) roof will keep some heat in, both reducing the rate of condensation and reducing the need for heat. If that means you turn down the propane heater, it will further reduce your condensation. With big gas heaters you need quite a bit of ventilation anyway

Comment: This lady is having a problem with a large tent which is outside.  Who better to answer tent problems than TGO?

Comment: Is it possible that the prior instances (with multiple tarps) allowed for more of the water vapor to escape, while the single large tarp is trapping it and condensing it, even with some ventilation hole? 

Certainly, an all-electric heating solution would produce less water vapor inside, but based on the prior experience, it wasn't necessary in the past.

Comment: In reply to the now-deleted answer (which should probably be reposted as a comment) - ground cover may help if the ground is wet.  Warm air evaporating water from the ground would add to the condensation, but a groundsheet would block this

Comment: FYI yes I'm new to this site so my apologies if I haven't followed protocol. It won't let me make a comment at all. It will only allow me to answer. So to the person who deleted my "answer" when I was trying to be polite and say Thank You to the nice people that have tried to help, my apologies to you in particular if it offended you for me saying Thank You. And yes I will try the ground cover and hopefully that will help out. Also put more thought into it and came up with some differences that I made this time which may be affecting the situation. I appreciate you responding to me even after

Comment: The reason it won't allow you to comment is that you're not logging in with the same details as you used in posting the question.  You can always comment under your own question but the system doesn't know you're you